# Posting multiple values from html submit form

Tags: php, html, json

I'm trying to use an HTML submit which is populated from an associative array from an SQL database, but I would like to pass multiple values as opposed to the usual 1. I've tried using JSON in the value, with the variables and then decode the JSON later to retrieve the individual variables.

```
<select name="name">
<?php
foreach($array as $vals){
  echo '<option value={"a":".'$vals['1']'.","b":".'$vals['2']'.","c":".'$vals['3']'.","d":".'$vals['4']'."}>Option Name</option>';
}?>
</select>
```

It works as intended until one of the options has a spacing in the string and then in the HTML page. I end up with a problem where somehow an extra " is inserted in the space, so my browser is showing the value:

```
{"a":"x" y","b":"xy","c":"xyz","d":"xyzz"}
```

The problem is the "x" y" which I was hoping to be "x y".

Does anyone have ideas on how I can fix this? Or equally any other methods of achieving the same result?

Comment: *"It works as intended until one of the options has a space in the string"* - Try to `trim()` it or `preg_replace()`.

Comment: Side note: `</submit>` isn't a valid closing tag.

Comment: Apologies, I mean select.

Comment: Look at {"a":"x" y","b":"xy","c":"xyz","d":"xyzz"} check  ".

Comment: Fetch the row as assoc and `json_encode` it.  If needed `array_combine` to add custom keys. Post an example of `print_r($vals);`

Comment: If you can get this values from some array __before__ submit - why can't you get them __after__ submit?

Comment: * small hint * in loop: `$array = ['a' => $vals[0], 'b' => $vals[1], 'c' => $vals[2]]`, in HTML: `<option value='<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>'>`. Also it's a good idea to move whole JSON into the `<script>...</script>` area as an variable and use it from your `option` without escape issues or use base64 encoding that will cause ~33% string extra size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the `value` attribute so that spaces don't terminate it. Also use `htmlentities()` to encode other special characters.

Also, don't construct JSON by hand, use `json_encode()`.

```
foreach ($array as $vals) {
    $obj = ["a" => $vals[1], "b" => $vals[2], "c" => $vals[3], "d" => $vals[4]];
    $json = htmlentities(json_encode($obj));
    echo "<option value='$json'>Option Name</option>";
}
```

Comment: Probably need `htmlentities()`.

Comment: Infact I can json_encode $vals and omit the $obj, much nicer way of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: @James That won't change the keys from `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` to `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.

Comment: Indeed it will not, $obj is needed then. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would build the JSON as a PHP array and then you can base64_encode(json_encode()) the array.   This would be easier to read and you don't have to worry about other edge cases with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the position of . and '

```
echo '<option value={"a":".'$vals['1']'.","b":".'$vals['2']'.","c":".'$vals['3']'.","d":".'$vals['4']'."}>Option Name</option>';
```

Corrected

```
echo '<option value={"a":"'.$vals['1'].'","b":"'.$vals['2'].'","c":"'.$vals['3'].'","d":"'.$vals['4'].'"}>Option Name</option>';
```